# How to manipulate a class from another class?

Tags: java, class, oop, methods

Working on a simple tic-tac-toe game in Java.

I have a class named `TicTacToe`, which contains most of the program.
And I have a class named `GameHelpers`, which should contain methods to help with the game.

Class `TicTacToe` contains an array (`JButton buttons[9]`), and an `int count` variable that stores how many Xs and Os the user has put on the screen already. (Each time the user clicks a button, it's blank text changes to an X or an O, and the count variable goes count++).

Currently, the only method I plan to write inside `GameHelpers`, is a method named `resetGame()`. This method should do two things:
1- Set the text on all the buttons in `buttons` blank.
2- Set `count` to 0.

If `resetGame()` was a method inside `TicTacToe`, it would be easy. It would look like this:

```
resetGame(){
     for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
          buttons[i].setText("");
     }
     count = 0;
}
```

But `resetGame()` should be a method inside a different class, `GameHelpers`.

I assume that what I'm trying to do is pretty standard object-oriented programming. There's a class with most of the program, and another smaller class with methods to help the bigger class. The program always revolves around the bigger class (`TicTacToe`).

I have two questions:

1- Is the idea described above (about one major class that the program revolves around, and smaller classes to help), standard and common in object-oriented programs?

2- How would you code the method `resetGame()` inside `GameHelpers`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1.- This technique can be used, but the less classes a program has to rely on the better. I don't see the problem with simply making the method #resetGame inside TicTacToe.

2.-

```
public class GameHelper {
public static void resetGame() {
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        TicTacToe.buttons[i].setText("");
    }
    TicTacToe.count = 0;
}
}
```

You could then call this method from TicTacToe by using:

```
GameHelper.resetGame();
```

In this case the class GameHelper is redundant, but I don't know the full intent of your program.

Comment: static variables are not good practice, he should better use private variables and public setter/getter

Comment: I'm aware it's not good to use statics, but I think his main question was simply how to call static methods from another class.

Comment: This doesn't work. It gives me an error (red line) under TicTacToe.buttons and TicTacToe.count. The error says: "Cannot make a static reference to non static field TicTacToe.buttons".

Comment: It would be bad practise, but you could declare your button variables as static, outside any method they are currently in.

Answer (score -1):

The best practice would be to write setter and getters for your count and your buttons like so: (for the count):

```
public int getCount() {
return count;
} 

public void setCount(int count) {
  this.count = count;
}
```

Then you can access it in your other class via:

```
TicTacToe ttt = new TicTacToe();
ttt.setCount(0);
```

Since you do not want a new instance of TicTacToe i suppose you could do something like this:
In GameHelper write `private TicTacToe ttt;` and then

```
public GameHelper(TicTacToe ttt) {
this.ttt = ttt;
}
```

Then you would not have to create a new instance but pass the instance when creating GameHelper. So in TicTacToe when you initialize GameHelper you would write `GameHelper gh = new GameHelper(this);`

Here i made a example for you:

```
    public class TicTacToe {

private int count = 0;

public TicTacToe() {
count = 3;
GameHelper gh = new GameHelper(this);
}

public void setCount(int count) {
this.count = count;
}

public int getCount() {
return count;
}
public void printCount() {
System.out.println("Count:"+count);
}
}



  public class GameHelper {

TicTacToe ttt;
public GameHelper(TicTacToe ttt) {
this.ttt = ttt;
this.ttt.setCount(5);
this.ttt.printCount();
}

}

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
TicTacToe ttt = new TicTacToe();
}

}
```